# Clear the client console in SSH2 for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I am building a command-line game that players will connect to over SSH. I have an SSH2 server script that responds to commands, but I would like to know if it is possible to clear the client console from the server?

I would like to have a cls/clear command that clears the console at a user's request, like the Unix command 'clear'.

Here is my code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var inspect = require('util').inspect;

var ssh2 = require('ssh2');
var utils = ssh2.utils;

var allowedUser = Buffer.from('foo');
var allowedPassword = Buffer.from('bar');
var allowedPubKey = utils.parseKey(fs.readFileSync('public.key')); ;

new ssh2.Server({
    hostKeys: [{
            key: fs.readFileSync('private.key'),
            passphrase: '<private key passphrase>'
        }
    ]
}, function (client) {
    console.log('Client connected!');

    client.on('authentication', function (ctx) {
        var user = Buffer.from(ctx.username);
        if (user.length !== allowedUser.length
             || !crypto.timingSafeEqual(user, allowedUser)) {
            return ctx.reject();
        }

        switch (ctx.method) {
        case 'password':
            var password = Buffer.from(ctx.password);
            if (password.length !== allowedPassword.length
                 || !crypto.timingSafeEqual(password, allowedPassword)) {
                return ctx.reject(['password'],false);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return ctx.reject(['password'],false);
        }

        ctx.accept();
    }).on('ready', function () {
        console.log('Client authenticated!');
        client.once('session', function (accept, reject) {
            var session = accept();
            session.on('shell', (accept, reject) => {
                var stream = accept();
                stream.write('Welcome to EnLore!\n\r');
                stream.on('data', data => {
                    var args = data.toString().replace("\n","").split(" ");
                    if (args[0] == '\r') return;
                    switch(args[0]) {
                        case 'exit':
                            stream.exit(0);
                            stream.end();
                            stream = undefined;
                            break;
                        case 'echo':
                            stream.write(args[1]);
                            break;
                        case 'clear':
                            // -------------- CLEAR CONSOLE HERE --------------
                            break;
                        default:
                            stream.write('Unknown command');
                            break;
                    }
                    stream.write('\n\r');
                });
            });
        });
    }).on('end', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
}).listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', function () {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + this.address().port);
});
```

**EDIT:**
I have found that writing \f to the stream will clear the current window, however, it only appends to the console, rather than clearing it